# SAS and SATA together in a RAID

Tags: raid, sata, hardware-raid, sas

I have to build a new server with SAS drives for RAID 10. However, I have 2TBs of storage on 2x1TB SATA drives.

Would it be possible to still plugin 2 SATA drives even if I run a hardware raid 10 with the OS on SAS drives?

Comment: are you saying you want to mix SATA and SAS in the same RAID array?  Or just use 2 SATA drives connected to a SAS controller?

Comment: No. The SAS will be in their own RAID 10. I just need the 2x1TB SATAs accessible :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Connect the SAS drives in their current array, and add in the RAID hardware card (assuming it fits) into your server. Connect the SATA cables up, and boot up your server.

Assuming the SATA drives have a partition already on them, they should show up in you `/dev/` folder (or My Computer, depending on the OS), but you may need to check the configuration.

Comment: and even if there is a small difference in size you can allow that in sas card bios under coercion (sometimes sas and sata drive might show some size difference)

Answer (score 0):

SAS controllers are able to read SATA drives.  So as long as you don't mix them in a RAID volume, it *should* work.  However, it's entirely dependent on your RAID controller.

It can't hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix SAS and SATA drives in the same array. The drives for each array must be of the same type. You can have different types in different arrays.

i.e. (numbers of disks not fixed, just an example)

You can ***not*** have

- Array 0: 3 x SATA + 2 SAS

You can have:

- Array 0: 5 x SATA
- Array 1: 5 x SAS